# Copy values with Python

Tags: python, button, odoo-8

I have a model with 2 field:

```
class res_partner(orm.Model):
    _inherit='res.partner'
    _columns={
        'expl_tour1':fields.many2one('member.formation.step', 'Tour 1'),
        'fast_assign':fields.many2one('member.formation.step', "Valeur d'assignation rapide"),

_def fast_assign_exploitation(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
            expl_tour1 = fast_assign
```

And in my view I have a button:

```
<button name="fast_assign_exploitation" type="object" string="Assignation rapide" class="oe_edit_only" />
```

But when I click the button, I have an error:

```
File "/var/packages/Odoo8/target/addons/member_formation/member_formation.py", line 70, in fast_assign_exploitation
    expl_tour1 = self.fast_assign
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/fields.py", line 701, in __get__
    record.ensure_one()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/models.py", line 5146, in ensure_one
    if len(self) == 1:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/models.py", line 5330, in __len__
    return len(self._ids)
AttributeError: 'res.partner' object has no attribute '_ids'
```

I just want to copy the value of the field `fast_assign` in the field `expl_tour1`. Do you know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `fast_assign`is a Many2one field you will just need to get the id.

```
class ResPartner(orm.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    _columns = {
        'expl_tour1': old_fields.many2one('member.formation.step', 'Tour 1'),
        'fast_assign': old_fields.many2one('member.formation.step', "Valeur d'assignation rapide")
    }

    def fast_assign_exploitation(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        partners = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
        for partner in partners:
            if partner.fast_assign:
                partner.expl_tour1 = partner.fast_assign.id
```

And Using the new API:

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    expl_tour1 = fields.Many2one('member.formation.step', 'Tour 1')
    fast_assign = fields.Many2one('member.formation.step', "Valeur d'assignation rapide")

    @api.multi
    def fast_assign_exploitation(self):
        for partner in self:
            # partner.expl_tour1 to get `expl_tour1 ` value.
            if partner.fast_assign:
                partner.expl_tour1 = partner.fast_assign.id
```

Comment: I am glad to help you